# creating different type of users

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

im creating a app that haves 2 type of users (employers and candidates). In my app i have 4 tables (users, candidates, employers, account_types),

```
users table :
- email, 
- name, 
- surname, 
- password 
- account_type

candidates table:
- id;
- user_id
- other columns

employers table:
- id;
- user_id
- other columns

accounts_type:
-id;
- title
```

So basically i have 2 different routes for each type of user, if is candidate could be like "domain.com/candidate/register" and if is employer would be "domain.com/employer/register". Im looking at the already ready code from laravel but im kinda strugglying the right way to do it. im on the  AuthController looking at the function create, but i need to create one more record, beside the record the users table, i need for example if is a employer, create a record and insert in the Employers table and vice versa if is a candidate. But i need to first check what type of account is being passed, i thought in using a hidden field in my registration form to indentify in the create function the type of user and then create some conditionals in the create function, but i dont think is very good approach.
So can someone guide me in the best way in passing the type of user in my registration without to create 2 different registrations controllers or functions and not passing hidden fields on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Here you had placed them in your database table. I use the same thing for normal users and admin in my application. for doing it I am using this in my controller.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$user_type = Auth::user()->account_type; //I hope you used 0 and 1 for two different accounts
//0 for employer and 1 for candidate

if ($user_type==1) {
         return view('domain.com/candidate/register');
    }else{
        return redirect('domain.com/employer/register'));
    }
```

I hope this will help you.